# Make JS carousel repeat

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I'm using the following code for a simple carousel. I'd like to make it repeat after you get to the third quote-item.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Here's the JS:

```
    <script>
show()
     $(function() {
    var currentCarousel = 0;
    function changeCarousel() {
      $('.quote-item').hide();
      $('.quote-item:eq('+ currentCarousel +')').show();
      currentCarousel = currentCarousel + 1;
      setTimeout(function(){ changeCarousel(); }, 8000);
    }
    changeCarousel();
    $('.quote-change').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      changeCarousel();
    });
      });
    </script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
 <div class="quote" >
  <div class="quote-item">
    <div class="quote-image">
      <img src="" alt="quote 1">
    </div>                                    
    <div class="quote-text">
        quote text one
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="quote-item">
    <div class="quote-image">
      <img src="" alt="quote 1">
    </div>                                    
    <div class="quote-text">
        quote text Two...
    </div>                                 
  </div>
    <div class="quote-item">
    <div class="quote-image">
      <img src="" alt="quote 1">
    </div>                                    
    <div class="quote-text">
        quote text THREE...
    </div>                                 
  </div>
<a href="#" class="quote-change">next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function () {
    var currentCarousel = 0;
    var timeoutID = null;
    var timeoutDuration = 2000;
    var quoteChange = $('.quote-change');
    var quoteItems = $('.quote-item');
    var numQuotes = quoteItems.length;
    
    function changeCarousel() {
        quoteItems.hide();
        quoteItems.eq(currentCarousel).show();
        currentCarousel += 1;
        if (currentCarousel === numQuotes) { currentCarousel = 0; }
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
            changeCarousel();
        }, timeoutDuration);
    }
    changeCarousel();
    quoteChange.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        changeCarousel();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote">
    <div class="quote-item">
        <div class="quote-image">
            <img src="" alt="quote 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-text">quote text one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-item">
        <div class="quote-image">
            <img src="" alt="quote 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-text">quote text Two...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-item">
        <div class="quote-image">
            <img src="" alt="quote 3" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-text">quote text THREE...</div>
    </div>
<a href="#" class="quote-change">next</a>

</div>
```

Also you were missing a `clearTimeout();` since you have a `click` handler calling the same `changeCarousel()` function as well. There is a conflict.

So imagine that by default, your `setTimeout` keeps calling `changeCarousel()` recursively and assuming it was right in the middle of another loop (4 seconds) when you decide to click on `next` button and jump to next carousel item by yourself. Because of that, your newly displaying carousel item will now only stay visible for the remaining 4 seconds but instead it should have had a full 8 seconds stay. Making sense?

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Update your changeCarousel so `if currentCarousel >= slides.length` it resets to `0`

```
    function changeCarousel() {
      $('.quote-item').hide();
      $('.quote-item:eq('+ currentCarousel +')').show();          
      if(currentCarousel >= slides.length ){
        currentCarousel = 0;
      } else{
        currentCarousel++;
      }
      setTimeout(function(){ changeCarousel(); }, 8000);
    }
```